# What did Lady Johanna ask of Dream?

Tags: comics, the-sandman, vertigo-comics

There was an episode where Dream sought the help of Lady Johanna Constantine to retrieve the head of Orpheus. Lady Constantine told him that the price of helping wouldn't be cheap. What was the price/prize Lady Constantine asked of him?

Answer (score 6):

I believe it is not stated explicitly anywhere. My theory is that when Dream said

> I will give you what it is in my power to give you

Lady Johanna accepted this as a general favor owed by a very powerful being, but ended up not using the favor while she lived. When she turns over Orpheus to the priests in charge of guarding him, she seems keen to see him again and suggests that she might return. Orpheus replies,

> I do not think that would be a good idea, Johanna. Goodbye.

This is followed by her monologue,

> I never saw him more. But, as the years have passed, I have, on occasion, seen him in my dreams.

And [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Sandman_characters#Johanna_Constantine), in the "The Dreaming" spinoff, there is an episode where

> Hettie [...] bribes Johanna for her silence, promising her that she would live to age 99. This promise proves true, with Johanna dying at age 99 while getting out of her wheelchair when she hears the song of her old companion, Orpheus.

Finally, in the first chapter of "Brief Lives", we see that Johanna is buried on the island where Orpheus is guarded by the priests, and the priests place a cherry blossom on her grave every spring day.

It seems that this is what Johanna (possibly after her death) asked from Dream - a wish only he could grant.

Comment: Johanna used to own the house where Dream was captured by Roderick Burgess. Could that have something to do with this??? plz rply.

Comment: @Dipak Yadav: That seems unlikely, since she died about 50 years before that event, and it's hardly something she would wish for.

Comment: I have a CRAZZZY theory! But I think Johanna liked Orpheus more than Dream and she might have thought that Dream was responsible for his condition (Hell! Of course he was!). So that could have been some sort of punishment.!!?????!!! IT IS A CRAZZY THEORY

Comment: @Dipak Yadav: well, the question is not so much whether it's crazy but whether there is anything in the comics to support it.

Comment: Thats True .Lets wait for The Sandman: Overture. I hope maybe some of my question will be answered

Comment: I'm a little out of the loop here - people are referring to "episodes". Is there an animated or live action version of the Sandman Saga? If so, is it true to the source material and worth the watch?

Comment: @Withywindle its an "episode" as an "event" or "scene" not as a "any one of the separate productions that constitute a serial." So far "Sandman" hasn't been filmed (to my best knowledge).

Comment: @Yasskier thanks - I couldn't find any information about live action productions. Now I realize we are talking about story arcs.